# init an NSNumber from enum element in mixed-language project

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums, nsnumber

I have a mixed-language project, Objective C and Swift, in XCode 6.

Singleton.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

enum  {
    enum_A = 0,
    enum_B,
    enum_C,
    enum_D,
    enum_E,
    enum_F,
    enum_G,
} enums;

@interface Singleton : NSObject

+ (id)sharedSingleton;

@end
```

Singleton.m

```
// Nothing's special in this file

#import "Singleton.h"

static Singleton *shared = nil;

@implementation Singleton

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Interface

+ (Singleton *)sharedSingleton {
    static dispatch_once_t pred;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{
        shared = [[Singleton alloc] init];
    });

    return shared;
}

@end
```

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let singleton = Singleton.sharedSingleton() as Singleton

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let n = NSNumber(char: enum_E) // ERROR HERE!!!
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

(Of course I had to setup bridging header file, having `#import "Singleton.h"` added).

The ERROR is:

> Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '(char: Int)'

It's strange that Swift can still recognize `enum_E` (I see it colorized in blue) but still pops up this error.
I tried `(char)enum_E` but still no luck.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried `NSNumber(int: enum_E)`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, apparently there actually is a difference between enums created in Objective-C and Swift. I assumed there was no difference, thus I only tested my approach in a Swift Playground.

---

**`enum` created in Swift**

```
// UInt32 used to have the same underlying type in both examples
enum TestEnum : UInt32 { 
    case A, B, C
}

var x = NSNumber(unsignedInt: TestEnum.C.rawValue)
// x == 2
```

To get the raw value from an enum value in Swift, you have to explicitly transform the enum value into the raw value. This can be done by adding `.rawValue` to your enum value.

---

**`enum` created in Objective-C**

Objective-C

```
enum TestEnum {
    A = 0,
    B = 1,
    C = 2
};
```

Swift

```
let x : TestEnum = C
var number = NSNumber(unsignedInt: C.value) // alternative: x.value
println("the number is \(number)")
// Outputs: the number is 2
```

The difference to the Swift enums seems to be that you have to use `.value` instead of `.rawValue` and you can not prefix them with the type. The raw type in this case is `UInt32`.

Tested in Xcode 6.1.1, iOS SDK 8.1, iOS Simulator 8.1

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Nero. I tried your approach but XCode alerts: **Int does not have a member named 'rawValue'**. I guess it's because my enum is defined in Objective C, not in Swift? Reference: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html), Raw Value section.

Comment: @quanguyen I assumed there was no difference. I updated my answer with code using an enum actually defined in Obj-C.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It simply works perfectly! However, in my code, the definition of `enums` is `enum {...} enums` while yours is `enum enums {...}`. If I take your code, Swift knows what `enums` is and works greatly as mentioned above; but if I take mine, it does not know my `enums`. I wonder if there is a way to use my code but Swift can still recognize my defined `enums`. Thanks

Comment: @quanguyen One can define enums in a lot of ways, so this would be better suited for a new question. With leaving out `TypeName` in `enum TypeName {...} instanceName;` you basically define a new **variable** named `instanceName` with the type `enum {...}`, and the type itself does not get a name. Doing a quick search, I found [this reference for C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/#enumerated_types), which should be quite similar to Obj-C enums, as both languages inherited them from C. Or maybe you can find an existing question here on StackOverflow.